# PHP gRPC ignores keepalive parameters

Tags: php, apache, grpc

I put these 3 parameters:

```
grpc.keepalive_time_ms=7200000
grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms=200000
grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls=1
```

in `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-grpc.ini`, `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/custom-php.ini`, `/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-grpc.ini` and `/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/custom-php.ini`. Then I restart webserver (whole Docker container) and list grpc config with `php -i | grep grpc` and they are missing from the output:

```
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-grpc.ini,
grpc
grpc support => enabled
grpc module version => 1.59.1
grpc.enable_fork_support => 0 => 0
grpc.grpc_trace => all,-timer_check => all,-timer_check
grpc.grpc_verbosity => debug => debug
grpc.log_filename => /var/log/grpc.log => /var/log/grpc.log
grpc.poll_strategy => no value => no value
```

I tested it with PHP 8.1, gRPC extension 1.45.0 and 1.59.1.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out these parameters dont belong to PHP .ini config files. They need to be in PHP code, passed as options array into gRPC client class constructor.

```
$options['grpc.keepalive_time_ms'] = 7200000;
$options['grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms'] = 200000;    
$options['grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls'] = 1;

$client = new Client('host:port', $options);
```